# Angular Spring boot on AWS Fargate

Tags: angular, spring-boot, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I want to deploy the angular, and spring boot applications on AWS fargate, I have added two containers for the angular and spring boot application. I have created one task for both containers But wanted to know how can do I communicate to my backend from angular without IP. I know to call with IP but I prefer not to do it that way as the IP change every time. Is there any way? I have tried with localhost to communicate between the containers,but it did not work as expected

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an Application Load Balancer, and configure your ECS Service to register tasks with the load balancer. Then you would use the address of the load balancer for your API calls from Angular to your backend.

Comment: +1 It won't work with localhost from the angular fronted as then it would be calling the client desktop and not the actual backend container.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Mark B, May I know what you mean address of the load balancer, sorry to ask such basic questions

Comment: The CNAME, DNS address of the load balancer. Do a google search for that if you don't understand what I'm saying.